# How to update multiple tables at the same time in Postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, function, sql-update, alter-table

So I have many tables in a db and I want to add two new columns for them.
For example, I have the columns "created_at" and "modified_at" and I want to create the columns "client_created_at" and "client_modified_at" 
and at the same time populate these new columns with the values of "created_at"  and "modified_at" of each table.

I imagine and have tried something like this:

```
ALTER TABLE patients, folders, auscultations, auscultations_notes, folder_ausc_association
    ADD COLUMN client_created_at bigint, client_modified_at bigint;

UPDATE patients, folders, auscultations, auscultations_notes, folder_ausc_association
    SET client_created_at = created_at, client_modified_at = modified_at
```

I'm not sure about how to structure it, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Maybe use some trigger. When update table patient, folders must be update, same for ausculations, etc...

Comment: any example on how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to the solution from Laurenz Albe, you could create an [`anonymous code block`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/sql-do.html) to do this job. Such a query can be very handy when you have many tables and don't want to create one statement per table.

```
DO $$
DECLARE
  row record;
BEGIN
    FOR row IN SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public' 
    LOOP
      EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE public.' || quote_ident(row.tablename) || ' ADD COLUMN client_created_at bigint, ADD COLUMN client_modified_at bigint;';
      EXECUTE 'UPDATE ' || quote_ident(row.tablename) || ' SET client_created_at = created_at, client_modified_at = modified_at;';
    END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

Note: This code block adds the columns you want into **all tables** in the schema `public` - use it with care! You can adapt it to the tables you need by changing this query in the block:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_tables WHERE schemaname = 'public'
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a statement per table for each of your two statements.

Define a maintenance window, and then perform for each table:

```
ALTER TABLE patients
   ADD client_created_at bigint, client_modified_at bigint;

UPDATE patients
   SET client_created_at = created_at, client_modified_at = modified_at;

ALTER TABLE patients
   ALTER client_created_at SET NOT NULL,
   ALTER client_created_at DEFAULT extract(epoch FROM current_timestamp),
   ALTER client_modified_at SET NOT NULL,
   ALTER client_modified_at DEFAULT extract(epoch FROM current_timestamp);
```

Use a different `DEFAULT` if you have different needs.

Comment: Thank's for your help. There isn't any way to avoid replicating this queries for each table? I have a lot of them...

Comment: The answer by @JimJones offers help for that.